# surround string values in single column with * character

Tags: mysql, string

I have a mysql database column that contains string values seperated by commas (e.g.: `apple, pear, orange, banana, grape`). I need to create an SQL statement that will insert a * on either side of each string value (e.g.:`*apple*,*pear*,*orange*,*banana*,*grape*`). I know how to take these values and parse them but not sure how to go about adding the * character. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE the_table
SET the_column = CONCAT('*', REPLACE(the_column, ', ', '*,*'), '*')
```